# Seam conversation analogue in Grails

Tags: grails, seam

**Seam** unifies each unit of work with **conversation** id. JSF page has certain structure to uniquely map client ajax/non ajax requests to corresponding Seam component (by cid, view id) operating with serializable/stateful beans. And no worry about multiple tabs in session, back/forward, objects holding in session and worring about memory leaks, etc.

**I wonder if Grails has something similar to described above either supported natively or through plugins?**

As I understand, Conversation scope in Grails is like JBPM pageflow without stateful bean support.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [WEBFLOW](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#webflow) is what your looking for.

Comment: From Grails guide: "Grails supports the creation of web flows built on the Spring Web Flow project. A web flow is a conversation...", I know about it, but little, and as I understand it doesn't satisfy my needs.